# The plugin `firebase_auth` doesn't have a main class defined in C:\Users\

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, dart

When adding firebase_auth to dependencies (pubspec.yaml) to my flutter project I'm getting this error:

The plugin `firebase_auth` doesn't have a main class defined in C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.1.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java or C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.1.3\android\src\main\kotlin\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.kt. This is likely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth` or `mainClass` entry in the plugin's pubspec.yaml.
If you are the author of this plugin, fix the `androidPackage` entry or move the main class to any of locations used above. Otherwise, please contact the author of this plugin and consider using a different plugin in the meanwhile.

My code is just the dummy code created by android studio and the only thing i added is firebase_auth: ^3.1.3 in pubsbec.yaml , the .json file in the android/app directory and registered the app on Firebase website.

I get the same issue in VS Code, so Android Studio is not the problem.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you added the firebase_core pugin because it is essential and if you did everything according to the documentation then ```flutter clean```  after that ```pub cache repair ``` will do the the work. then again run

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: @your welcome. Kindly marked my answer as a solution so, other can get benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Add the firebase_core pugin because it is essential and if you did everything according to the documentation then flutter clean after that pub cache repair  will do the the work. then again run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't added Firebase core in your pubspec.yaml file. Try to add `firebase_core 1.7.0` in your pubspec.yaml and then clean your project using this command `flutter clean`

also Checkout this [installation guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/overview/)

Answer (score 0):

for issues like
"The plugin `X` doesn't have a main class defined in..."

Steps:

1. Delete pubspec.lock
2. Delete C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev.cache folder
3. Delete packages liked with plugin 'X' under above directory
4. Run 'flutter clean'
5. Run 'flutter pub get'

Done